# How to upload multi-images from Android to Spring Server?

Tags: android, spring, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to upload multi-images from Android to Spring Server, using Retrofit2, but it is not working.

I refer to this website: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-server

My code is below:

```
package com.example.gdtbg.fileupload;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.utils.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import gun0912.tedbottompicker.TedBottomPicker;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 100;

    private int PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

    ArrayList<Uri> test;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        test = new ArrayList<Uri>();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }

        Button uploadbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);



        uploadbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                TedBottomPicker tedBottomPicker = new TedBottomPicker.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setOnMultiImageSelectedListener(new TedBottomPicker.OnMultiImageSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onImagesSelected(ArrayList<Uri> uriList) { //this function return Uri file uri type("file://")

                                uploadAlbum(uriList);


                            }
                        })
                        .setSelectMaxCount(3)
                        .setEmptySelectionText("선택된게 없습니다! 이미지를 선택해 주세요!")
                        .create();



                tedBottomPicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager());



            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {

            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                } else {

                }
                return;

            }

        }

    }

    @NonNull
    private RequestBody createPartFromString(String descriptionString) {
        return RequestBody.create(
                okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);
    }

    public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) throws FileNotFoundException{
        String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID },
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
                new String[] { filePath }, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
            Uri baseUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media");
            return Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, "" + id);
        } else {
            if (imageFile.exists()) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
                return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }


    private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, Uri fileUri) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java
        // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri

        File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        Uri castedUri = getImageContentUri(getApplicationContext(), file);

        // create RequestBody instance from file
        try {

            Log.d("testfile", castedUri.toString());


            if(cr.getType(castedUri)==null)
            {
                Log.d("testfile", "content uri is null");
                Log.d("testfile", cr.getType(castedUri).toString());

            }
            else
            {

                Log.d("testfile", "content uri is not null");
                Log.d("testfile", cr.getType(castedUri).toString());


            }





            RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(cr.getType(castedUri)),file);




            // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
            return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }
    }


    private void uploadAlbum(List<Uri> fileUris) {
        final EditText description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.3:8089/Test/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        UserClient client = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);

        ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();

        Log.d("giduck", "Hello World!");
        Log.d("giduck", "" + fileUris.size());


        for (int i = 0; i < fileUris.size(); i++) {

            Log.d("sendTest", fileUris.get(i).toString());
            Log.d("sendTest", "" + fileUris.size());

            try {
                parts.add(prepareFilePart(""+i, fileUris.get(i)));

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("giduckfinal", "" + fileUris.get(i).toString());
            Log.d("giduckfinal", "in loop");


        }

        Log.d("giduckfinal", "this is final position 1");

        Call<ResponseBody> call = client.uploadAlbum(

                createPartFromString(description.getText().toString()),
                parts );

        Log.d("final", "this is final position 2");


        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success that Upload Image to Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail that Upload to Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }

}
 
 
package com.example.gdtbg.fileupload;

import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Multipart;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Part;

/**
 * Created by gdtbg on 2017-06-21.
 */

public interface UserClient {

  /*  @Multipart
    @POST("uploadForm")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadPhoto(
            @Part("description") RequestBody description,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part photo

            );

    @Multipart
    @POST("uploadForm")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadPhotos(
          @Part MultipartBody.Part profile,
          @Part MultipartBody.Part panorama

    ); */

    @Multipart
    @POST("uploadForm")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadAlbum(
            @Part("description") RequestBody description,
            @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files

    );



}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for people to wade through. Have you implemented the functionality you want and you have a bug, or are you wanting to add that functionality but do not know how? Either way, please try to cut the code down to a much smaller example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I resolved this problem just ago, it caused by Server's problem. Server didn't made ArrayList's Object. Thanks for your interesting.

Comment: OK, would you consider adding an answer below, by clicking "Answer Your Question", if you think that would be useful for future readers?

Comment: Okay, Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this code and it works for me

upload.php

```
 <?php

$attachment = $_FILES['attachment'];
define ("MAX_SIZE","9000");
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg"); 
// Method to extract the uploaded file extention
 function getExtension($str)
  {
     $i = strrpos($str,".");
     if (!$i) { return ""; }
     $l = strlen($str) - $i;
     $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
     return $ext;
 }

// Method to extract the uploaded file parameters
function getFileAttributes($file)
{
$file_ary = array();
$file_count = count($file['name']);
$file_key = array_keys($file);

for($i=0;$i<$file_count;$i++)
{
    foreach($file_key as $val)
    {
        $file_ary[$i][$val] = $file[$val][$i];
    }
}
return $file_ary;
}

// Check if the POST Global variable were set
 if(!empty($attachment) && isset($_POST['dirname']))
  {   
$dirname = $_POST['dirname'];

$uploaddir = "/var/www/html/uploads/".$dirname."/";

//Check if the directory already exists.
if(!is_dir($uploaddir)){
    //Directory does not exist, so create it.
    mkdir($uploaddir, 0777, true);
}   

$file_attributes = getFileAttributes($attachment);
//print_r($file_attributes);

$count = count($file_attributes);
$response["status"] = array();
$response["count"] = $count; // Count the number of files uploaded
array_push($response["status"], $file_attributes);

$file_dirs = array();

foreach($file_attributes as $val)
{       
    $old_file = $val['name'];
    $ext = getExtension($old_file);
    $ext = strtolower($ext);

    if(in_array($ext, $valid_formats))
    {
        $response["files"] = array();
        $new_file = date('YmdHis',time()).mt_rand(10,99).'.'.$ext;
        move_uploaded_file($val['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$new_file);
        $file_dirs[] = 'http://192.168.50.10/gallery/uploads/'.$dirname."/".$new_file;
    }
    else
    {
        $file_dirs[] = 'Invalid file: '.$old_file;
    }
}

   array_push($response["files"], $file_dirs);

    echo json_encode($response);
     }
?>
```

then in xml put this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="toegy.com.testmultiupload.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/select"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="select"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

     </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and in your activity put this

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView select;
int PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = 1;
String imageEncoded;
List<String> imagesEncodedList;
ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    select = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.select);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Log.e("++data", data.getClipData().getItemCount() + "");
            List<Uri> uriList = new ArrayList<Uri>();

            for (int i = 0; i < data.getClipData().getItemCount(); i++) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                Log.e("uri",selectedImage+"");
                uriList.add(i,selectedImage);

            }
            uploadPhotos(uriList,"photos");


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void uploadPhotos(final List<Uri> uriList, final String folderName) {
    pDialog.setMessage("uploading ...............");
    pDialog.show();
    List<MultipartBody.Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Uri uri : uriList) {
        parts.add(prepareFilePart("attachment[]", uri)); // Note: attachment[]. Not attachment
    }

    RequestBody requestBodyFolderName = createPartFromString(folderName);
    HashMap<String, RequestBody> requestMap = new HashMap<>();
    requestMap.put("dirname", requestBodyFolderName); // Note: dirname

    FileUploadService service = RetrofitClient.getApiService();
    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.uploadMultipleFilesDynamic(requestMap, parts);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            if (response.code() == 200) {
                // multiple dynamic uploads were successful
                Log.e("status", "done");
                pDialog.hide();
            } else {
                Log.e("status", "not done " + response.code());
                pDialog.hide();

            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.code()+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.e("status", "not done " + t.toString());


        }
    });
}
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, Uri fileUri) {

    File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(fileUri));
    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
}

private RequestBody createPartFromString(String descriptionString) {
    return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), descriptionString);
}
```

}

it will work prefect